# Is it possible to configure Cypress for starting in fullscreen mode?

Tags: cypress

I'd like to use a fullscreen mode for working with Cypress GUI, actually what F11 does. Can  I automate this process by adding correspondent config options to cypress.json?

And one more related question: is it possible to config the Zoom of the browser window displayed in Cypress GUI?

Answer (score 5):

The Cypress Plugins file supports a [Browser Launch API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html) which gives you the opportunity to modify the browser preferences, install extensions, add and remove command-line arguments, and modify other options.

Lucky for you, the Cypress documentation includes an example to do exactly what you're looking for. See the Browser Launch API's ["Start Fullscreen" example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Start-fullscreen).

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
      launchOptions.args.push('--start-fullscreen')

      return launchOptions
    }

    if (browser.name === 'electron') {
      launchOptions.preferences.fullscreen = true

      return launchOptions
    }
  })
}
```